# The flow files are getting queued in Merge content of NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Apache Nifi. I went through a problem where the Merge Content processor of Nifi has huge chunks of file queued. I really dont know how to take those files out of the queue. There is no errors and the files are getting queued for no reason.

Even if we stop the processor and list the queue it says **queue has no flow files**

Below is the screenshot of the same. I really appreciate if I can get some resolution on the same.

[image]

**Connection Details**

[image]

**QUEUE ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Files queued because merge processor unable to collect buckets of files to merge. Probably you have inconsistent parameters for merge. Try to stop source and target processors, increase back pressure size (because your queue is red - reached size limit), restart nifi (not sure if this required) - then try to view queue...

Comment: @daggett: I have taken all these steps in place. but still no resolution.. any other thought why this is not moving the flow files?

Comment: it's not moving because merge config is wrong. your question is about why you don't see flow files - right?

Comment: Please review the answers for these similar questions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397281/nifi-data-stuck-in-queues-when-load-balancing-is-used/71397466#71397466 and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841760/nifi-flowfiles-piling-up-before-mergerecord/69851387#69851387 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281757/nifi-mergerecords-leaving-out-one-file/70282988#70282988

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nifi - FlowFiles piling up before MergeRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841760/nifi-flowfiles-piling-up-before-mergerecord)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is checking what the flow files have inside of them and if there is data that NiFi can actually merge together. If there isn’t any data to be able to merge, try to clear the queues and determine how to get the data into a state that they can be merged.
What this means is that if flow file A has fields A, B, and D, and flow file B has fields F, J, and L, see if you can get common fields together so they can be merged.